# cmake call causes error: "Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 224: _dl_check_map_versions: Assertion `needed != ((void *)0)' failed!"

Tags: opencv

I am in the process of installing OpenCV on Ubuntu following the tutorial: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

I reached Step 10 and am installing version 3.1.0. However, when making the call to cmake in the second part of Step 10, I receive the following error: "Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 224: _dl_check_map_versions: Assertion `needed != ((void *)0)' failed!"

Outside of the specific flags attached to the cmake call in the tutorial, any call to cmake in general causes the same error to be returned.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have attempted reinstalling both libcurl3 and cmake. I have attempted installing cmake from their own webpage rather than through terminal and have found no change in the error.

Comment: Why do you think it is a CMake or Phython issue?

Comment: Well I assumed it was a cmake issue, not a python issue, because i only get this error with the cmake command. 

Upon doing an apt-cache depends command for cmake I came across conflicts so I am currently resolving those now.

Comment: I've built my own version of libcurl, and there is also a system version of this library. If I have both of them on path (with the custom one taking precedence), I get this error. Using just the system version works ok.